# Run PHP file inside ASP.NET MVC 4 application on IIS 7?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, iis

I have one payment gateway that has only php api. Is it possible to run that script inside my IIS server on application that will run MVC4?

When I add `1.php` to my root folder and try to navigate it it shows `HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found`.

Comment: `HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found`

Comment: May be a problem with URL routing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install PHP with FastCGI on the IIS server. That should configure it to support .php extension. It can be installed with http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Next you have to configure the routing to ignore requests to this page (otherwise it will assume that the name is actually a name of a controller).

Comment: Yea, I installed PHP via WebPlatform installer and now I can run PHP scripts w/o even modifying routes. Paldies.

Comment: How would I configure the routing to ignore anything with the `.php` extension?