# How can I execute PHP code from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to do something like the following:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // Redirect to the phpinfo.php file
    public ActionResult PhpInfo()
    {
        return RedirectToRoutePermanent("~/Views/Home/PhpInfo.php");
    }
}
```

This errors out saying that the route cannot be found.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Zain

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @scartag: I'm trying to add a link to the PhpInfo page for my site.  I need a way to execute some php

Comment: if you already have php installed and supported in the virtual directory / site you could use the absolute url .. you don't have to use an action http://sitename/phpInfo.php you'll need to move PhpInfo.php to the root though.

Comment: @scartag: How do I use an absolute url? Do you mean manually specifying <a href="/PhpInfo.php">PHP Info</a> in the html, or is there a more indirect way to do it?

Comment: Yes you can simply specify <a href="PhpInfo.php">Php Info</a> if php is supported on the virtual directory / site it should work.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Just for my knowledge, is there no way to do it from the C# code?

Comment: You should install something like [FastCGI for IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13254554/153923) to actually support PHP files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from scartag in the comments. Stating it below for posterity:

It doesn't seem to be possible using the C# part of ASP.NET, but you can post links by using `<a href="/PhpInfo.php">PHP Info</a>` syntax