# How to view php pages in my mvc application

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, razor, steam

I'm new to php. I have made some php code and I would like to run it within my mvc application together with razor. How is it possible for me to do so? I basically want to implement my steamlogin php script into the autogenerated homepage on mvc.

This is a school project!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run PHP in the project (ASP.NET MVC) as html page (dynamic files) but you can't return a .php file from Controller.

[How can I execute PHP code from ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917624/how-can-i-execute-php-code-from-asp-net-mvc)

As it's school project, it's look like you have write some functionality in PHP. You can send POST request to .php file handle the code in the .php file and show the response.